# Caffe python prediction is different when using c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, caffe

I'm trying to convert python code that predicts on trained caffe model to c++, but I'm getting different prediction results.

The input layer looks like this:

```
name: "*"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 224 dim: 224 } }
}
```

now the python code using transformers like the follows:

```
caffe_transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
    caffe_transformer.set_transpose('data', (2, 0, 1))  # move image channels to outermost
    caffe_transformer.set_mean('data', np.array([104, 117, 123]))  # subtract the dataset-mean value in each channel
    caffe_transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255)  # rescale from [0, 1] to [0, 255]
    caffe_transformer.set_channel_swap('data', (2, 1, 0))  # swap channels from RGB to BGR
```

My c++ code is based on the caffe c++ classification example but i Changed the Preprocess function:

```
void CaffeClassification::Preprocess(const cv::Mat& img,
                            std::vector<cv::Mat>* input_channels) 
{
  cv::Mat sample;
  cv::resize(img, sample, cv::Size(256, 256));
  cv::Rect roi(16, 16, 
    input_geometry_.width, input_geometry_.height);
  cv::Mat crop = sample(roi); 

  crop.convertTo(crop, CV_32FC3);
  crop -= cv::Scalar(123, 117, 104);

  cv::split(crop, *input_channels); 
}
```

But python code gives my correct results while c++ code doesn't.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i don't know If this is the reason but if you are using floating-point numbers check how to c++ code save and move them in python 2.5 in cpp it could be saved as 2.4999973

Comment: I'm converting from python to c++, but anyway I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: I fount out what was the problem. I read the first output float instead the second where the result found :\